# Ubuntu 12.10 Nvidia GT555M Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, bumblebee

I have laptop with Nvidia GT 555M video card.
 System Ubuntu 12.10, kernel Linux 3.5.0-17-generic

1. step what i do:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
   ```

   restart system

   ```
   optirun glxgears
   ```

   This message give me:
   Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver 
   Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
2. Open `sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and change `Driver=` to `Driver=nvidia` and `KernelDriver=nvidia-current` to `KernelDriver=nvidia`. Restart the system and run `optirun glxgears`.

   This message gives me:

   ```
    The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
    Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
   ```

Anybody have idea?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KernelDriver=nvidia-current` is correct if you have installed the `nvidia-current` package, you should not change that on Ubuntu. Since Ubuntu 12.10, you need to install the kernel headers yourself.

So, revert your `KernelDriver` change (the `Driver=` one does not matter) and install the kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

This should automatically build the nvidia module. When this is completed, reboot or start the Bumblebee daemon:

```
sudo start bumblebeed
```

Then try running `optirun glxspheres` again.

Comment: Thank you Man! It`s working! Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

There is even a better way to manage Optimus graphic card on Linux: it's called Primus, it depends on Bumblebee. Just follow the instructions right there and we'll get even better results (I have the same graphic card than you, and it's working amazingly well): http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html
However, don't forget to `vblank_mode=0 primusrun` instead of `primusrun` alone. You can test `glxgears` with it.
Once it's installed, if you wish, you can still use `optirun`.

Here's a proof of the above: 
[image: Pretty badass to me]

Answer (score 0):

**Symptoms**

Ubuntu 12.10 (Mint 14) + Bumblebee `optirun` works once right after installation and then after reboot it never works with error message:

```
The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
 Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

After reboot `bumblebeed` is not running, there is no `/proc/acpi/bbswitch` file, `bbswitch` module is not loaded.

**Problem**

`bumblebeed` doesn't start after reboot.

**Solution**

After some investigation I've found a solution/hack/bug/younameit.
Open terminal and execute

`sudo nano /etc/init/bumblebeed.conf`

Search for text

```
start on    (login-session-start or desktop-session-start)

stop on     (desktop-shutdown)
```

and replace it with

```
start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

Save file, reboot and enjoy.